# Uses of dittany of Crete (origanum dictamnus)

Tags: spices, greek-cuisine, oregano

Last summer I went to Crete for a short vacation, and came back with fond memories of the local cuisine.

Before leaving I bought some spices, among them a small bag of diktamo (dittany, or dictamnus).

While the smell is quite nice, I found that it doesn't impart any discernible flavour to dishes.

I tried it in some recipes that call for oregano (homemade pizza, some pasta sauces), but I'm curious as to its use in Greek cuisine; maybe I'm just using it the wrong way.

Comment: I'm sure that having travelled all the way from Omnia to Ephebe, you must have tried it with tortoise. [My apologies to the people who don't get that reference, & probably also to the ones who do ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin, no but my Brutha has... apologies to all for bad puns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Greece we use diktamo mostly for tea, as beverage.
You can try it by boiling water in a jar and put 5-10gr diktamo for 5-10 minutes.
Other uses as any other tea leaves. For example you can boil milk or 35% milk cream  and put diktamo and then use the milk or cream to make pastry cream or ganache or any other similar.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origanum_dictamnus#Aroma_profile), I found that apart from oregano, this plant has [several](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thymol) [flavour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carvacrol) [compounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-Cymene) in common with thyme and cumin. You could try combining it with those flavours, or using it in a context where thyme or cumin would make sense. Wikipedia (both the English as well as the Greek page) also suggests brewing a herbal tea from this with some supposed medicinal benefits.

Answer (score 0):

is often use as an aromatic component in the production of vermout, liquors and parfumes. due to his antiseptic propertie it can alsobe  brewed and consumed as a natural remedy for cold, mouth infection and improve digestion